# in tsung how to increase port limitation (65k)

Tags: performance, port, load-testing, ejabberd, tsung

i am new in ejabberd. i'm going to test load on ejabberd using tsung tool.

In tsung configuration file i set max users to 100,000. but i have encounterd max 65000 local port range. error : addrinuse.

please help me how to make more than 65000 connections from one client via Tsung.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how many concurrent connections do you plan to have in your test scenario.

Consider using Tsung cluster (multiple test servers) or simply configure and use an additional IP. Whichever is more suitable for your scenario.

If your test server has additional IPs, you can specify them like this:

`<client host="T1" weight="1" cpu="8" maxusers="500000">
  <ip value="192.168.1.25"/>
  <ip value="192.168.1.26"/>
</client>`

For the cluster configuration, check the official documentation.

Comment: that's it !! thanks for your help. I added some virtual network adaptors and some IP tag in client section of tsung config.